# Getting Product ID from URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extract

i need to get the product id from an url into a var

https://instrumentall.md/ro/6167922/

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript use `window.location.href` to get the value of the url. Than process it as a normal string.